# Pandas slice by key from concat()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have read in a number of excel files and concatenated them into one dataframe. I've also added keys so I know which excel file any given piece/chunk of data came from. Knowing which file data came from is extremely important for my work.

My excel files all end with numbers that increase. E.g. _00, _01, _02, _03, etc.

```
path = os.getcwd()
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
allFiles.sort() # put files in numerical order
# e.g. _00, then _01, then _02, and so on

keys = [[] for x in range(len(allFiles))]
for idx, name in enumerate(allFiles):
    keys[idx] = name[-7:-5] # returns numbers 00, 01, 02, etc.

df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(f) for f in allFiles), keys = keys)
```

Now that I have all this data all in one dataframe, how can I access all the data with any given key? For example I'd like to make a histogram of all the data from the first excel file; the one with the key `'00'`

Is having everything in one dataframe even the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df1 = df.xs('00')
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.loc['00']
```

EDIT:

It seems your code should be simplify:

```
df = pd.concat({f[-7:-5]: pd.read_excel(f) for f in allFiles})
```

Comment: I'd set your answer as the answer, but StackOverflow won't let me for another 10 mins. I'll be back then

Answer (score 0):

I think having it all in the same data frame is preferable and would strongly recommend not splitting it.
I would recommend something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(df[df["column"]== '00'])
plt.show()
```

(with 'column' being the column containing information on which file the line comes from and '00' being the specific value).